# Filter by Date with Spring Data MongoTemplate

Tags: spring, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I would like to filter my filedA's array by dates, with a mongo query it looks like that :

```sql
    {
        $project: {
            user: "$$ROOT",
            fieldA: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$fieldA",
                    as: "a",
                    cond: {
                        $and: [
                            {$lt: ["$$a.constraint", new Date()]}, 
                            {$gt: ["$$a.constraint", new Date()]}
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
           }
     },
```

The query works but I have trouble when I tried to do it with spring :

```java
project()
    .and("$$ROOT").as("user")
    .and(
        filter("$fieldA")
            .as("a")
            .by(
                and(       
                    ComparisonOperators.Lte.valueOf("a.constraint")
                        .lessThanEqualTo(dateEnd),                                              
                    ComparisonOperators.Gte.valueOf("a.constraint")
                        .greaterThanEqualTo(dateStart)
                )
            )).as("fieldA"),
```

I think this is not the right way to make dates comparations but I don't know how to do it properly. Could help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try wrapping your `dateStart` and `dateEnd` variables in `ConvertOperators.ToDate.toDate`.
The `ComparisonOperators` methods (in this case `lessThanEqualTo` and `greaterThanEqualTo`) accept either `String` or `AggregationExpression`.

By using the `ConvertOperators.ToDate.toDate` method, you ensure that the passed argument is `AggregationExpression` and the value is correctly formatted for comparing.

Result would look like this:

```
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.ConvertOperators.ToDate.toDate
...

project()
    .and("$$ROOT").as("user")
    .and(
        filter("$fieldA")
            .as("a")
            .by(
                and(       
                    ComparisonOperators.Lte.valueOf("a.constraint")
                        .lessThanEqualTo(toDate(dateEnd)),                                              
                    ComparisonOperators.Gte.valueOf("a.constraint")
                        .greaterThanEqualTo(toDate(dateStart))
                )
            )).as("fieldA"),
```